# Where to Download Cancer Raw Reads (fastq)?

Tags: rna-seq, ngs, fastq

Does anyone know where I can download cancer raw reads (fastq files), tumor and Germline for non-humans?

I wanted to make a study with human data but I don't have the control access to download raw reads.

Comment: So do you want human or non-human? Your question is confusing. For human, have a look at [Is there a publicly available tumor-normal sample?](//bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/q/4111). Is that what you need?

Comment: Please tell us when you cross-post your question. This question is also asked on [biostars](https://www.biostars.org/p/365077/).

Answer (score 2):

You can try to browse SRA (sequence read archive) at https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/sra. 
To download fastq files from SRA, you'll need their sratoolkit: https://trace.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/Traces/sra/sra.cgi?view=software.

The easy command to download fastq files by their accession number is :

```
fastq-dump --split-files accession_number
```